# Is there Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome version with Wubi installer?

Tags: installation, 12.10, gnome, windows, wubi

The question says it all. I want to have Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome version. I can't find any Wubi version. Is this even possible?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 uses Gnome... if you mean the Gnome Remix, that's not an official derivative.

Answer (score 2):

No, you would need to first intall Ubuntu with wubi and then install gnome-shell.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

There is a gnome remix. It is an unofficial version of Ubuntu that ships with gnome-shell, but I do not think they support wubi.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10

http://ubuntu-gs-remix.sourceforge.net/p/home/

Answer (score 1):

Just install with the Wubi then after the install run:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

There you go, Wubi with Gnome Shell.